# What are the main hypotheses or postulates that are currently being reviewed and studied in Earth Sciences?

Tags: history-of-science

Very similar to what happens in other sciences, I would like to know, ¿What are the main hypotheses or postulates that are currently being reviewed and studied in Earth Sciences?

Comment: You can think on [Big Date](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jsg.2018.05.007), [Planetary Geology](https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/5/9/eaaz2484.full), [Geology Differentiation](https://doi.org/10.1190/tle38010060.1)...

Comment: Mr editors, I think the question is clear, is just one and not ambiguous : ¿What are the main hypotheses or postulates that are currently being reviewed and studied in Earth Sciences?

Comment: Thanks David García, geology differentation is really what I am looking for. Is the new paradigm.

Comment: The question is very clear, but very broad. This website is best suited for specific focused questions.